# How to Create a Smooth Scrolling Navigation with jQuery using a dropdown list instead of a nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've created this smooth scrolling navigation bar using html and some jQuery however I would like to just use a dropdown list instead of the full blow navigation bar. So I want to get rid of the nav bar and just create a dropdown list that functions the same way. How would i go about doing this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main-nav li a').click(function(e) {

    var targetHref = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

section {
  margin: 300px 0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#main-nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-nav li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #373737;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#submit-case">Submit a Case</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="about">
  <h2>About Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="how-it-works">
  <h2>How It Works Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="submit-case">
  <h2>Submit a Case Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <h2>Contact Section</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the existing code and built a very simple dropdown menu for you.

HTML:

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
  <li id="dropdown_menu">Dropdown
    <ul id="the_menu" class='hidden'>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#submit-case">Submit a Case</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<section id="about">
  <h2>About Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="how-it-works">
  <h2>How It Works Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="submit-case">
  <h2>Submit a Case Section</h2>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <h2>Contact Section</h2>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

section {
  margin: 300px 0;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#main-nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#dropdown_menu { 
  padding: 15px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dropdown_menu:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#main-nav li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #373737;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main-nav li a').click(function(e) {

    var targetHref = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(targetHref).offset().top
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  // dropdown
  $("#dropdown_menu").click(function() {
    $("#the_menu").slideToggle('hidden'); 
  })
});
```